# Two table views into a single View Controller?

Tags: swift, tableview, viewcontroller

I want to create a new section but without imageView, what do I need to do? Because if I let the string blank (nil not accepted) the titleLabel is going to be aligned with the titleLabel in the first section. I want to make the title in the second section align 20 from the left (with no image) 
Do I have to create another model for the sections I want with no Image?
Can I add a new section without Image inside cellForRowAt??

```
fileprivate var CELL_ID = "CELL_ID"


fileprivate var aerealCell: [[AerealCellModel]] = [
    [
        AerealCellModel(image: "aereal_icon", title: "Aereal", arrow: "chevron.right")
    ],
    [
        AerealCellModel(image: " ", title: "Indice de Masa Corporal", arrow: "chevron.right"),
        AerealCellModel(image: " ", title: "Clasificación ASA", arrow: "chevron.right"),
        AerealCellModel(image: " ", title: "Riesgo Cardiaco de Gupta", arrow: "chevron.right"),
        AerealCellModel(image: " ", title: "Escala de Riesgo de Lee", arrow: "chevron.right"),
        AerealCellModel(image: " ", title: "Peso Ideal", arrow: "chevron.right"),
        AerealCellModel(image: " ", title: "Tamaño de Tubo Pediátrico", arrow: "chevron.right"),
        AerealCellModel(image: " ", title: "Clasificacion de Mallampati", arrow: "chevron.right")
    ]

]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor  = .systemBackground

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles  = true
    setupTableView()

}

fileprivate func setupTableView() {
    tableView.register(AerealCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CELL_ID)
}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return aerealCell[section].count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 54
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as! AerealCell
    let aerealMainCell = aerealCell[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]


    cell.aerealCalcCell = aerealMainCell
    return cell
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return aerealCell.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = section == 0 ? "CALCULADORA PRINCIPAL" : "OTRAS CALCULADORAS    (Premium Members)"
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(label)
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    view.backgroundColor = .systemGray6
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .light)

    return view
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 54
}}
```

[image]

Comment: You can create and use two different cells

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1: Place your UI elements in a horizontal stackView**

You can add both the `imageView` and `titleLabel` in a horizontal stackView and apply constraints to it. When there is no imageContent the label adjusts itself to the start position given that there is no widthAnchor to the `imageView`. This is a much simpler approach

**Approach 2: If you don't want to place elements in StackView**

Remove any trailing anchor/constraint associated with the `titleLabel`. Just add a leading constraint relative to your `imageView` and don't add any widthAnchor to it.

The titleLabel will align itself to the `imageView` start position when there is no imageView content(imageView width will be `0`)

Comment: I think those option are not an option. imageView is a String type in the model and anytime I left "" blank, constraints will remain for the absent image. so Im stuck. 

Answer (score 0):

1. Set width constraint to image view in cell.
2. Whenever you don’t want to display image, set image width constraint to 0.